# Unable to install elementary 64-bit

Tags: system-installation, grub, 64-bit

I have a 64-bit machine, and I am installing the 64-bit version of elementary OS. I have removed my previous OS.

I just want elementary, so I am doing a full installation.
So I select the option to wipe the entire hard disk and install elementary. But at the end it gives the error message "grub-pc failed to install into /target/". I don't understand, I am not partitioning anything manually.

Then why am I getting this problem? I searched on the net and found that sometimes we face a problem due to an existing EFI partition of Windows 8 and above. But I don't have Windows 8. Do I need to create an EFI partition?

If I need to create EFI partition, Kindly tell me how to do it.

For now I am using 32-bit version, I didn't have any problem with it. But I want 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and solved it by connecting my pc to internet using ethernet. This will repair the grup-pc on the fly and will fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing elementary without the internet connection.
Only after you get the os to install, you should troubleshoot your internet connection.

Check this link for details: [grub-pc package fails to install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199049/how-to-fix-a-failing-grub-pc-package-installation-in-hyper-v-virtual-machine)

Comment: Yes, my system was connected to internet. But still same issue..

Comment: Install the operating system without connecting to internet. After you have installed it, then connect your system to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

To create an EFI partition, with GParted:

- Create a minimum 100 MB partition formated in fat32 (250MB recomended)
- Apply changes (green OK logo)
- Select your partition and go into partition -> manage flags, select boot, esp (I don't really know what esp is but it is selected on my efi partition and I have read somewhere that you need it)

Note : The efi partition shoud be a primary partition (number 1 to 4), and can be anywhere on the disk. Placing it at the begining is not safe (still works on my computer).

Then when you will install elementary OS, it should use it by default if you choose one of the "automatic" choices, and if you chose something else, you will need to click on your partition, click change, and mount it as /boot/EFI.

Comment: I do _not_ agree that 100 MB or even 250 MB is enough. I have regularly had various boot areas exceed 1 GB in space.

Comment: Look at what is used in your EFI partition. For me with Ubuntu MATE, windows 10 and elementary OS, I have 73MB used. I readed on Internet sevral times that 200 or 250 is the standart size, and that you really shoud'nt use less than 100 MB